# Cannot match schema from a file which has nested array

Tags: karate

Assume that I have a response-Json look like below

```
def resJson =
  """
      {
         "id": 1,
         "code": "OU82883",
         "features":
           [
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "class": "OU8811",
                    "school": "parent",
                    "course": "abc",
                    "sortOrder": 123
                }
           ]
      }
   """
```

To be easily manage file to compare, I am placing the expected schema - expected result in a file ("getCourseDetails.txt"), with structure below

```
{
    id: '#number',
    code: '#string',
    features: ##[{
           id: '#number',
           class: '##string',
           school: '##string',
           course: '##string',
           sortOrder: '#number'
      }
    ]

}
```

Then in executed feature file, perform the code as

```
* json expSchema= read ('../Data/Schema/getCourseDetails.txt')
* match resJson == expSchema
```

The system informs AssertionFailed Error

To find another way to validate schema, I kept only the structure inside of "features" in "getCourseDetails". The outside of "features", I put into executed feature file. So my code now is:

*GetCourseDetails file*:

```
 {
     id: '#number',
     class: '##string',
     school: '##string',
     course: '##string',
     sortOrder: '#number'

 }
```

Feature file:

```
* json courseDetails= read ('../Data/Schema/getCourseDetails.txt')
* def expSchema = {id: '#number', code: '#string', features: '##[] courseDetails'}
* match resJson == expSchema
```

There is no error and validate works well, but this approach is not my expected.

I would like to know is there a way to centralize all things in a file, and user just calls the file to validate against actual response's schema

Thank you so much.

Comment: @Peter: done for your link, and if you have any ideas or source/link , please feel free to share my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-engineering your tests, but you can use JS to do advanced set-up and building the schema the way you want, and it will be re-usable. For example:

`first.json`:

```
{ "foo": "#string" }
```

`second.json`:

```
{ "value": "#number" }
```

`schema.js`:

```
function() {  
  var first = read('first.json');
  karate.set('second', read('second.json'));
  first.bar = '##[] second';
  return first;
}
```

now your feature file can be:

```
* def schema = call read('schema.js')
* def response = { foo: 'test', bar: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}] }
* match response == schema
```

Above, if you `* print schema` you will see:

```
{
  "foo": "#string",
  "bar": "##[] second"
}
```

And if you want a one-liner - `* match response == call read('schema.js')` should work !